# "Object Required" Error with Collections

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my VBA code, I try to eliminate the duplicates of a list of reimbursement while accumulating the values of columns B and C, but this is with conditions, i mean to eliminate a duplicate it is obligatory that the values of the columns A and H are identical to the values A and H of the duplicate line so it is necessary to have the two conditions to remove a duplicate, thank you for your help 
this is the code I have previously built but it gives me "object required" error

[excel table of the vba code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N36Sy.png)

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Cel1 As Range
Dim Plage As Range
Dim Plage1 As Range
Dim Col As New Collection
Dim col1 As New Collection
Dim Cumul As Double
Dim Cumul1 As Double
Dim DerLig As Long, i As Long, j As Long, MémoL As Long, p As Long
Dim PremL As Boolean
Dim CodeADELI As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Col = New Collection
Set col1 = New Collection
On Error Resume Next



With Worksheets("Feuil1") 'Nom de feuille à adapter
    DerLig = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DerLig1 = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Les Codes ADELI sont placés dans une collection afin d'obtenir une liste sans doublon
    Set Plage = .Range("A2:A" & DerLig)
    Set Plage1 = .Range("H2:H" & DerLig1)

    For Each Cel In Plage
    If Cel <> "" Then Col.Add Cel, CStr(Cel)
    Next Cel

    For Each Cel1 In Plage1
    If Cel1 <> "" Then col1.Add Cel1, CStr(Cel1)
    Next Cel1

    On Error GoTo 0

    'On boucle sur chaque élément de la collection que l'on compare aux codes de la liste.
    For i = 1 To Col.Count
        For p = 1 To col1.Count

    Cumul1 = 0
    Cumul = 0 'Initialisation du total
    MémoL = 0
    PremL = True

        CodeADELI = Col(i)
        INSEE = col1(p)

        'chaque élément de la collection est comparé aux codes de la liste.
        For j = DerLig To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("A" & j).Value = CodeADELI And .Range("H" & j).Value = INSEE Then
                'On ajoute le montant au cumul
                    Cumul = Cumul + .Range("B" & j).Value
                    Cumul1 = Cumul1 + .Range("C" & j).Value
                    'S'il s'agit de la première ligne , on mémorise le numéro de ligne
                    If PremL Then
                        MémoL = j
                        PremL = False
                    'Sinon, on supprime la ligne (doublon)
                    Else
                        .Rows(j).Delete
                        MémoL = MémoL - 1
                        DerLig = DerLig - 1
                        DerLig1 = DerLig
                End If
            End If

        Next j

        'Le cumul est affecté au montant de la ligne  qui reste
        If MémoL > 0 Then .Range("C" & MémoL) = Cumul1
        If MémoL > 0 Then .Range("B" & MémoL) = Cumul

         Next p
    Next i

    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of lines of code there - perhaps you could narrow down the problem and mention **which** line gives the "object required" error.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` followed after many, many statements (including loops) by `On Error GoTo 0`, with no attempt to check `Err.Number` is a recipe for bugs. In effect, you have `On Error Hide Bug` at the top of your code.

Comment: If you have `Set Col = New Collection` then there is no point in also using `Dim Col As New Collection`. Just declare as `Dim Col As Collection`. That isn't an actual bug, but is still a code infelicity.

Comment: In addition to getting rid of `On Error Resume Next`, you might want to consider adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declaring all of your variables. For example, `DerLig1` isn't declared anywhere. Without `Option Explicit`, a simple typographical error can lead to a hard to find bug (especially when you are also using `On Error Resume Next` to tell VBA to hide the bug from you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be fixed by changing the lines

```
If Cel <> "" Then Col.Add Cel, CStr(Cel)
```

and

```
If Cel1 <> "" Then col1.Add Cel1, CStr(Cel1)
```

to

```
If Cel <> "" Then Col.Add CStr(Cel), CStr(Cel)
```

and

```
If Cel1 <> "" Then col1.Add Cstr(Cel1), CStr(Cel1)
```

---

The error is caused by the fact that later in your code, where you are using `col(i)` and `col1(p)`, the collection was referring to a range object which had been deleted by the line of code saying `.Rows(j).Delete`.

By changing the collection to be just the value of the cell, rather than the cell itself, it won't be destroyed by the deletion of the row.

---

A `Dictionary`, or simply a dynamically dimensioned `String` array, may be a better way of keeping track of which "keys" you wish to match on.

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim Cumul As Double
    Dim Cumul1 As Double
    Dim DerLig As Long, i As Long, j As Long, MémoL As Long
    Dim PremL As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dict = New Dictionary

    With Worksheets("Feuil1") 'Nom de feuille à adapter
        DerLig = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To DerLig
            If Not dict.Exists(.Cells(i, "A") & "|" & .Cells(i, "H")) Then
                dict.Add .Cells(i, "A") & "|" & .Cells(i, "H"), .Cells(i, "A") & "|" & .Cells(i, "H")
            End If
        Next

        For Each key In dict.Keys

            Cumul1 = 0
            Cumul = 0 'Initialisation du total
            MémoL = 0
            PremL = True

            'chaque élément de la collection est comparé aux codes de la liste.
            For j = DerLig To 2 Step -1

                If key = .Cells(j, "A").Value & "|" & .Cells(j, "H").Value Then
                    'On ajoute le montant au cumul
                    Cumul = Cumul + .Range("B" & j).Value
                    Cumul1 = Cumul1 + .Range("C" & j).Value
                    'S'il s'agit de la première ligne , on mémorise le numéro de ligne
                    If PremL Then
                        MémoL = j
                        PremL = False
                    'Sinon, on supprime la ligne (doublon)
                    Else
                        .Rows(j).Delete
                        MémoL = MémoL - 1
                        DerLig = DerLig - 1
                    End If
                End If

            Next j

            'Le cumul est affecté au montant de la ligne  qui reste
            If MémoL > 0 Then .Range("C" & MémoL) = Cumul1
            If MémoL > 0 Then .Range("B" & MémoL) = Cumul

        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Note:  I'm not sure whether any of your original code comments still make sense - I didn't try to translate them to see what they were saying.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `Col` is conceptually wrong.

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()
    ' 28 Sep 2017

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long

    With Worksheets("Feuil1")
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' columns 1 = A, 8 = H
        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)) _
               .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 8), Header:=xlNo
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rl, "B"))

        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(Rl, "B").Value = Application.Sum(Rng)
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(Rl, "C").Value = Application.Sum(Rng.Offset(0, 1))
    End With
End Sub
```

As you see, with a different concept you need much less code. Or, in reverse order, the concept to which the use of `Col` led you required more effort than would otherwise have been needed.

Comment: WIthout knowing the issue please do not post guesswork as an "answer". Without option explicit set col = new collection is valid and creates the collection object.

Comment: @Zerk I think that my answer is helpful because it enables the OP to continue his work. What does your comment contribute?

Comment: That is the difference between a comment an an answer. An answer solves the issue or problem or shows how to do it. My comment merely corrected your incorrect information. We haven't been given enough information to solve the problem, therefore answers should not be posted yet.

Comment: @John Coleman Yes. Without the fault I had assigned to the use of `Col` I wouldn't have posted this as an "answer".

Comment: Although I would usually use an array instead of a collection, there is nothing in the OP's use of the collection that seems to point to it being "conceptually wrong".  (And the values being placed into the collections appear to be "keys", which are then used to determine which values will be totalled from other columns, i.e. the value to be totalled isn't the value being added to the collection.)

Comment: what happens is the macro turns and verifies the conditions well but when the conditions are true it cumulates the values of columns B and C but after it makes me the error "object required" and stops at the line CodeADELI = Col (i)

Comment: I don't think your revised code will work.  By removing "duplicate" records as the first step, you will have lost the information necessary to create the totals in the remaining records.  (Plus the revised code is just placing a "grand total", of the remaining records, into the final record, rather than placing a "total" into each of the remaining records.)

Comment: @YowE3K My code is tested and working. You provided a solution working the way the OP wants. Therefore our discussion here is about whether or not the use of a Collection was "conceptually" correct. I notice that your solution doesn't use one :-)

Comment: (a) OK, point taken :D  The code "works", but it doesn't produce the OP's required results (i.e. creating a total by "key" of the values in the existing data, and replacing the existing data with a single record per "key" with the appropriate total within each respective record).  (b)  My "solution" uses a collection - it was just a simple change of `cel` to `CStr(cel)` when populating the collection.